# Using Shareplum to access a Sharepoint Document Library and getting an error when updating metadata

Tags: sharepoint-online, shareplum

I am using Shareplum to upload a file to Sharepoint, and then to update the files metadata.  This is all working fine until I hit 5,000 documents in my document library, at which point its failing. The file upload still works fine, but when I run the following code to then update the metadata of the file I just uploaded, I get a 500 Server Error.
`

```
  instanceOfDocumentLibrary = self.site.List(self.sharePointFolder)
    fields = ['Name', 'ID']
    query = {'Where': [('Contains', 'Name', self.fileName)]}
    print("Getting Items")
    GetData = instanceOfDocumentLibrary.GetListItems(fields=fields, query=query)
```

`
It fails at the GetData stage.   I suspect what is happening is that when the List is instantiated (instanceOfDocumentLibrary) it only contains 5,000 documents (as per the SharePoint 5,000 document view limit), and so when we do the GetListItems it can't find the 5,001th document that we've just uploaded (self.fileName) because instanceOfDocumentLibrary only contains 5,000 documents.

I'm pretty much a novice here, so any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems it can't be done using this methodology, as it is a limitation of SharePoint online.

I've therefore switched to using a different library (Office365-REST-Python-Client) which does things in a different way, and seems to work very well for me.